# cftransaction not rolling back create tables on error

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, transactions, coldfusion-9

So this might just be a fundamental failure in my understanding of the `cftransaction` tag.

I have a bunch of Create Table SQL statements, one after the other, and in one of them there is an error, these are wrapped in a giant `cftransaction`, however when the error occurs, it doesn't rollback the create statements.

```
<cfset variables.x = 0>
<cftry>
<cftransaction action="begin">
    <cfquery name="variables.qTables" datasource="dev_db">
        CREATE  TABLE  `dev_db`.`tbl_entries_import` (  
            `p_id` int( 11  )  default NULL ,
            `p_Title` varchar( 255  )  default NULL ,
            `p_FirstName` varchar( 255  )  default NULL ,
            `p_unique_email` varchar( 255  )  default NULL ,
            PRIMARY  KEY (  `p_ID`  ),
            UNIQUE KEY `p_unique_email_UNIQUE` (`p_unique_email`)
          ) ENGINE  = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET  = utf8;
    </cfquery>
    <cfset variables.x++>
    <cftransaction action="setsavepoint" savepoint="#variables.x#"/>

    <cfquery name="variables.qTables" datasource="dev_db">
        CREATE  TABLE  `dev_db`.`tbl_entry2office_import` (  
            `entryID` int( 11  )  NOT  NULL default  '0',
            `officeID` int( 11  )  NOT  NULL default  '0'
            PRIMARY  KEY (  `entryID`  ) 
        ) ENGINE  = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET  = utf8 COLLATE  = utf8_unicode_ci;
    </cfquery>
    <cfset variables.x++>
    <cftransaction action="setsavepoint" savepoint="#variables.x#"/>
</cftransaction>
<cfcatch>
    <cfloop from="#variables.x#" to="1" index="variables.y" step="-1">
        <cftransaction action="rollback" savepoint="#variables.y#">
    </cfloop>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

So after the second `cfquery` (which should cause an error), I would expect the table from the first `cfquery` to not exist in my schema, but currently it will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` statements cause an implicit commit, according to the docs: "[13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html)":

> The statements listed in this section (and any synonyms for them) implicitly end any transaction active in the current session, as if you had done a COMMIT before executing the statement.
>
> Data definition language (DDL) statements that define or modify database objects. ALTER DATABASE ... UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME, ALTER EVENT, ALTER PROCEDURE, ALTER SERVER, ALTER TABLE, CREATE DATABASE, CREATE EVENT, CREATE INDEX, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SERVER, **CREATE TABLE**, DROP DATABASE, DROP EVENT, DROP INDEX, DROP PROCEDURE, DROP SERVER, DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE.

(my **emphasis**)

Comment: +1 to Adam's answer.  You can clean up after yourself if needed to put drop statements in the catch block.  In other transactional news, be wary of truncate.  It's in the block that Adam posted.  Some people truncate instead of delete from table.  This is speedy but not transactional.